# how do I go about fixing "list index out of range" error?

Tags: list, csv, dictionary

I have a csv and tsv file i had to create into a dictionary and list. I have to combine them to get a specific output, but I keep getting this "list index out of range" error and I'm not sure what I have to do.

This is the code I've been using.
import csv

```
    def make_happy_dict():
        filename = 'happiness.csv'
        happy_dict = {}
        with open(filename, "r") as infile:
            infile.readline()
            happy_csv = csv.reader(infile)
            for row in happy_csv:
                happy_dict[row[0]] = row[2]
        return happy_dict

    def read_gdp_data():
        Data = []
        countries = open("world_pop_gdp.tsv", 'r')
        Lines = countries.readlines()

        happy_dict = make_happy_dict()  # Step 1

        for line in Lines:
            line = line.split("\t")
            country = line[0].strip()  # Get the country name
            line[1] = line[1].replace(",","")
            line[2] = line[2].replace('$',"")
            line[2] = line[2].replace(',',"")
            line[2] = line[2].replace('\n',"")
            happiness = happy_dict.get(country)  # Step 2
            if happiness is not None:  # Step 3
                line.append(happiness)
            Data.append(line)
        return Data

    def main():
        GDP = read_gdp_data()
        for index in GDP:
            print(index[0]+","+index[1]+","+index[2]+","+index[3])  # Step 4
    
    main()
```

I've been able to print the dictionary and then the list on their own sucessfully but not together.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting "list index out of range" its because you are trying to index an element in the list that doesn't exist. Check that in your list you have 4 indexes of data.